# AtomicReference compareAndSet: String reference vs value equality

Tags: java, atomic

let's say you have:

```
AtomicReference<String> ref = new AtomicReference<>("");
bool ok1 = ref.compareAndSet(x1, x2); // x1 has value "", x2 has value "test"
bool ok2 = ref.compareAndSet(x3, x4); // x2 has value "test", x4 has value "updated"
```

What will be the value of "ok2" (and thereby, the value of "ref") in the following scenarios.

1. x2 and x3 are one and the same reference, i.e. x2 == x3
2. They aren't, i.e. x2 != x3 (but x2.equals(x3))

My understanding is that in scenario 2, the update would fail, i.e. ok2 is false.

If my understanding is correct there, what's the best way to reproduce this behaviour with value-equality? In other words, how would you set up an atomic compareAndSet operation that works on string equality (i.e. effectively ok==true in both scenarios) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a loop, by extracting the value, comparing, and then updating unless the value changes in between extracting and attempting to update:

```
static <T> boolean setIfEqualTo(AtomicReference<T> ref, T old, T value) {
  T current;
  do {
    current = ref.get();
    if (!Objects.equals(current, old)) {
      // They're not equal, so give up on trying to update.
      return false;
    }
  } while (
      // Try to update, if the value is still equal to `current`.
      !ref.compareAndSet(current, value));
  return true;
}
```

Unless heavily contended, this won't loop, or may loop once (if you're unlucky) or twice (if you're really really unlucky).